# Sonar runner 2.3 throws exception with Sonar 3.7 --> IllegalDataException

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to analyse Java project using SOnar 3.7 & sonar-runner 2.3.

I was successfully able to analyse same codebase using Sonar 3.6.1 & Sonar runner 2.2.1 with same rule set/profile.

However, when I have upgraded version then I am having following errors...

org.jdom.IllegalDataException: The data "null" is not legal for a JDO
M attribute: A null is not a legal XML value

**Console Output :**

```
SonarQube Runner 2.3 Java 1.6.0_30 Sun Microsystems Inc. (64-bit) Windows 7 6.1 amd64 
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on. 
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\Dhruba\InstallationFolder\Sonar\sonar-runner-2.3\conf\sonar-runner.properties 
INFO: Project configuration file: C:\Dhruba\Projects\Elsevier-OPSBANK_II_AIS\R11_Service_Workspace\sonar-project.properties 
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is  platform dependent) 
INFO: Work directory: C:\Dhruba\Projects\Elsevier-OPSBANK_II_AIS\R11_Service_Workspace\.sonar 
INFO: SonarQube Server 3.7 
13:38:29.376 INFO  - Load batch settings 
13:38:29.482 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\Dhruba\.sonar\cache 
13:38:29.487 INFO  - Install plugins
13:38:31.219 INFO  - Install JDBC driver 
13:38:31.227 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521 /orcl
13:38:32.382 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate 13:38:34.579 INFO  - Load project settings 
13:38:34.665 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
13:38:34.788 INFO  - -------------  Scan OPSBankIIUtilityService
13:38:34.790 INFO  - Load module settings 
13:38:35.382 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=OBBase1,language=java] 
13:38:35.394 INFO  - Excluded sources: 
13:38:35.394 INFO  -   **/*_*.java 
13:38:35.394 INFO  -   **/bo/** 
13:38:35.395 INFO  -   */stub/** 
13:38:35.395 INFO  -   **/*FacadeSoap*.java    
13:38:35.395 INFO  -   com.ibm.ejs.container._EJSWrapper_**/src 
13:38:35.395 INFO  -  *_Deser/src 
13:38:35.395 INFO  -   *Proxy.java 
13:38:35.395 INFO  -   */*FacadeHome.java 
13:38:35.395 INFO  -   */*FacadeLocalHome.java 13:38:35.395 INFO  - com/elsevier/obii/xml/* 
13:38:35.395 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
13:38:35.395 INFO  -   */package-info.java
13:38:35.430 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins 
13:38:35.502 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis 
13:38:35.532 INFO  - Compare over 7 days (2013-09-14) 
13:38:35.558 INFO  - Compare to previous version
13:38:35.734 INFO  - Base dir: C:\Dhruba\Projects\Elsevier-OPSBANK_II_AIS\R11_Service_Workspace\OPSBankIIUtilityService 
13:38:35.734 INFO  - Working dir: C:\Dhruba\Projects\Elsevier-OPSBANK_II_AIS\R11_Service_Workspace\.sonar\dhrsrvc_OPSBankIIUtilityService 
13:38:35.735 INFO  - Source dirs: C:\Dhruba\Projects\Elsevier-OPSBANK_II_AIS\R11_Service_Workspace\OPSBankIIUtilityService\src 
13:38:35.735 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US 
13:38:36.090 INFO - Sensor JavaSourceImporter... 
13:38:37.021 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 931 ms 
13:38:37.021 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor... 
13:38:37.160 INFO  - Java AST scan... 
13:38:40.518 INFO  - Java AST scan done: 3358 ms 
13:38:40.763 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 3742 ms 
13:38:40.764 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor... 
13:38:40.765 INFO  - parsing C:\Dhruba\Projects\Elsevier-OPSBANK_II_AIS\R11_Service_Workspace\.sonar\dhrsrvc_OPSBankIIUtilityService\build\surefire-reports
13:38:40.767 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 3 ms 
13:38:40.769 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor... 
13:38:40.770 INFO  - SonarEngine is used
13:38:40.846 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled 
13:38:41.511 INFO - Sensor CpdSensor done: 742 ms 
13:38:41.511 INFO  - Sensor CheckstyleSensor... 
13:38:41.514 INFO  - Execute Checkstyle 5.6...
13:38:41.534 INFO  - Checkstyle configuration: C:\Dhruba\Projects\Elsevier-OPSBANK_II_AIS\R11_Service_Workspace\.sonar\dhrsrvc_OPSBankIIUtilityService\checkstyle.xml
13:38:43.845 INFO  - Execute Checkstyle 5.6 done: 2331 ms
13:38:43.849 INFO  - Sensor CheckstyleSensor done: 2338 ms
13:38:43.850 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor... 
13:38:43.853 INFO  - Execute PMD 4.3... 
13:38:43.864 INFO  - Java version: 1.5 
13:38:44.008 INFO  - Execute PMD 4.3 done: 155 ms 
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE 
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Total time: 17.761s Final Memory: 15M/406M 
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
 org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
     at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
     at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
     at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
     at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
     at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41) Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.XmlParserException: org.jdom.IllegalDataException : The data "null" is not legal for a JDOM attribute: A null is not a legal XML value.
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:55)
     at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:72)
     at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:114)
     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:142)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:186)
     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:181)
     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:179)
     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:174)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:156)
     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
     at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
     ... 9 more
**Caused by: org.jdom.IllegalDataException: The data "null" is not legal for a JDO M attribute: A null is not a legal XML value.**
     at org.jdom.Attribute.setValue(Attribute.java:486)
     at org.jdom.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:229)
     at org.jdom.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:252)
     at org.jdom.Element.setAttribute(Element.java:1109)
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdProfileExporter.exportPmdRulesetToXml(PmdProfileExporter.java:126)
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdProfileExporter.exportProfile(PmdProfileExporter.java:63)
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.createRulesets(PmdExecutor.java:107)
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executeRules(PmdExecutor.java:89)
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executePmd(PmdExecutor.java:75)
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.execute(PmdExecutor.java:61)
     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:52)
     ... 37 more ERROR: ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

*Can you please help to resolve this one ?*

Answer (score 0):

I was analyzing the issue and found that imported profile from Sonar 3.6.1 to 3.7 had  issue. Sonar 3.7 was not able to parse few of the XPath rules.

Therefore, I have just removed those XPath rules and re-added them manually and it starts working. This issue is not a bug of Sonar-runner instead Sonar 3.7 could not restore profiles correctly.